# Is this how I find the rate of change of internal energy for filling a vessel?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, energy, thermodynamics

If I am filling a tank with something (lets say air) and both its volume and pressure are changing with time (It's not rigid), it it safe for me to say:

$$u=h-Pv$$

$$\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{dh}{dt}-P\frac{dv}{dt}-v\frac{dP}{dt}$$

I used the product rule when I differentiated the $Pv$ term

Comment: The application of the product rule seems fine, but are the variables here?

Comment: yes i have all the variables. I just wanted to know if that step was right. I was given the expression for the change in pressure, and i determined change in $v$ with the ideal gas law. and i found dhdt by the energy balance

Comment: Sorry, that should say "what are the variables here" (on my phone)

Comment: @KyleKanos how would I use the T-ds equation to find an expression for $\frac{ds}{dt}$? I wanted to use $T\frac{ds}{dt}=\frac{du}{dt}+P\frac{dv}{dt}$ but T in the tank is changing with time. And it doesn't look like i could apply the product rule to that since it's already in the differential form